# Can hardware decoding of h.264 be enabled in Kodi on Ubuntu?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, video, kodi, h264

Running Ubuntu 23.04 (and previously 22.10) on a Pi 4 doesn't seem to allow me to hardware decode h.264 in Kodi from Debian from the Ubuntu repo. I draw this conclusion from the `Video decoder: f-h264 (SW)` shown in Kodi while playing a 480p or 720p video.

Is it possible to enable this hardware decoding in Ubuntu, or do I need another Kodi build (and by extension another OS)?

Comment: Personally, I would try Raspberry Pi OS - if Kodi uses hardware decode in that, then the issue is Ubuntu